# RAILS_ENV is not working as expected. How to set the environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-5, development-environment

I'm configuring a new app in rails5 on my localhost and am having some trouble establishing my environment.  I set my environment variable to "development" but whenever I run `rake db:drop` it says the following

```
ActiveRecord::ProtectedEnvironmentError: You are attempting to run a destructive action against your 'production' database.
If you are sure you want to continue, run the same command with the environment variable:
DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1
```

However my environment is set to development and not production:

```
sam$ printenv | grep RAILS_ENV
RAILS_ENV=development
```

What am I forgetting?

Many thanks for taking a look at this.

EDIT: My yaml looks like this

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  username: ZZZZZZZ
  database: YYYYYYY
  host: 127.0.0.1
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
  password: XXXXXXXXX

development:
  <<: *default
  reconnect: true
```

Comment: Do you have a configuration block for production on your database.yml? try removing that config and maybe you get a better error

Comment: @arieljuod good suggestion I commented all other environments out.  Currently my yaml is as displayed above in the edit I made to the question.  However the error remains unchanged.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could set the environment using 
`bin/rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development`

Answer (score 2):

In case the DB you wanted to drop was a production copy, the `ar_internal_metadata` would hold the value `production` and `rails db:drop` throws the error you see. Running migrate changes the value to development

```
rails db:migrate
...
ActiveRecord::InternalMetadata Update (0.4ms)  UPDATE "ar_internal_metadata" SET "value" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "ar_internal_metadata"."key" = $3  [["value", "development"]
...
```

Now you can **drop db without error**. No point on importing then dropping perhaps, but I got this error now after having played around with data in local rails console and wanted to drop and restore data.